# encode Include/require output to json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, header

I have an already built complex php application that doesn't work by the MVC design pattern and doesn't have a built-in templating system (twig etc).

What happens is that instead of getting a variable at the end that contains the template (html out put) -> it prints the html (include 'foo/somepagethatcontainshtmlandphp.php').

My problem? that page is requested from a remote server with ajax. I want to get that page encoded by JSON. and decode it on the remote server with json.parse.

**My Question:**

How can I encode an already printed out html output and render it to JSON. is it even possible?

Structure of my files:
template/sometmp.php

```
<html>
  <head>
   <?php echo 'some shitty way to use html and php together'; ?>
  </head>
<body>
<?Php echo 'some lame php and html code written in the same place'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.php

Remote Server:

```
$.ajax (
      .....
      .....
      success: function(data) {
          console.log(JSON.parse(data));
      }
);
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What do you mean by saying: "render it to JSON"? JSON is a format of data storage. This phrase makes no sense to me.

Comment: It doesn't have to be JSON to be parsed with javascript, you could just take the HTML and place that somewhere on your page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use output buffering. E.g.:

```
ob_start();
include 'foo/somepagethatcontainshtmlandphp.php';
$html = ob_get_clean();

echo json_encode(array(
    'some_data' => ...,
    'html' => $html
));
```

Please, treat this code as a sketch, something you should start with. There are more things to consider, e.g. *should I be using include or require* or *should I be using JSON or simply text response*. The answers are up to you and depend on further logics of your application/website.

More info about output buffering **[in the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)**.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question right you can simple buffer the output of the include file give the buffer to json_encode and output this.

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'foo/somepagethatcontainshtmlandphp.php'
$output = ob_get_clean()
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

this could be parse by Javascript as json.